# Сортировка английских слов по алфавиту в С++

Tags: c++

Как упорядочить массив английских слов по алфавиту?

Comment: С алгоритмами сортировки вы знакомы?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать стандартный алгоритм сортировки. [**Например**](http://ideone.com/v0XViE):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::string> myvector;
    myvector.push_back("five");
    myvector.push_back("one");
    myvector.push_back("nine");
    myvector.push_back("abc");
    std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
    for(auto&x:myvector)std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

А можно использовать изначально контейнеры, которые сразу упорядочат Ваш массив (std:map, std::multimap, std::set, std::multiset). [**Например**](http://ideone.com/AXbfoF):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set <std::string> myset;
    myset.insert("five");
    myset.insert("one");
    myset.insert("nine");
    myset.insert("abc");
    for(auto&x:myset)std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```